# Delay background music from starting

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, appdelegate

I am working my through an app and adding features that I would like but running in to a few issues as I go along.

I was hoping someone would have an answer to this question.

I want some background music on my app and I have achieved this by using this code in my AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


    NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/smb1-1.mp3"];
    NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
    NSError* err;

    //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

    if( err ){
        //bail!
        NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        //set our delegate and begin playback
        player.delegate = self;
        [player play];
        player.numberOfLoops = -1;
        player.currentTime = 0;
        player.volume = 0.5;

    }

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

So all is good. However what I would like is for the audio to start playing 3 seconds after the app has finished launching and not straight away.

Does anyone know how I can set a delay on this or maybe explain a different way. I don't there to be a delay before every time the music repairs, just for the first initial launch.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help:

1. Create an BOOL iVar in your appDelegate:

   ```
   @implementation aaaAppDelegate        
   {
       BOOL firstTime;
   }
   ```
2. Add this to your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
   {
       // Override point for customization after application launch.
       firstTime = YES;
       return YES;
   }
   ```
3. Add this to your applicationDidBecomeActive method in the appDelegate.

   ```
       - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
       {
           if (firstTime)
           {
               firstTime = NO;
               [self performSelector:@selector(playMusic) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
           }
       }
   ```
4. Move your music playing code from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to a separate method called playMusic:

   ```
    -(void)playMusic
    {
        NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
        resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/smb1-1.mp3"];
        NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
        NSError* err;

        //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
        [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

        if( err ){
            //bail!
            NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
        }
        else{
            //set our delegate and begin playback
            player.delegate = self;
            [player play];
            player.numberOfLoops = -1;
            player.currentTime = 0;
            player.volume = 0.5;

        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Absolutely amazing - Thank you so much Emily J - this worked exactly as I wanted it to.